# How to add a JXDatePicker to a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, swingx

I'm trying to add a JXDatePicker to a JLabel and I follow the next 2 steps:

1. Initialize the JXDatePicker:

   JXDatePicker datePicker = new JXDatePicker(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
2. Add to JLabel

   datePickerLabel.add(datePicker);

When I run the application I don't get errors nor warnings but I cannot see the date picker I only see the JLabel default text.

[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JerWF.png)

What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: JLabel missing any LayoutManager in API ..., is would needed to define that programatically

Comment: @mKorbel How can I add a LayoutManager?

Comment: [JLabel.setLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setLayout(java.awt.LayoutManager))

Comment: Kind of wonder why - why not just add the `JLabel` and picker to the same container and use an appropriate layout manager to align them

Comment: I just did that, I changed my initial idea and create a container (JPanel) and a separate JLabel. Having this, I just set the layout and add the JXDatePicker to the container and everything works fine as I expected.